# Shipping Cost in Shopping Cart Page?

Tags: checkout, shopping-cart

I am working on Product e-commerce responsive website. It has shipping cost that we are showing in check-out page based on the shipping address entered by the user. 
The problem is, after entering the shipping details if user goes back to the shopping cart page, should be show the shipping cost and Tax in cart page based on the selected address??

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

**If you're able you should do it.**
Everything to assist the user in any way possible.
It will reduce frustration, cognitive load and it will enhance the user experience, simply because they'll have to do less (which is remembering what the actual price was with shipping costs).

I assume they also don't have to fill in their address for the second time when they enter the checkout procedure again?

Answer (score 1):

Delicate problem this one. On one hand a user have supplied information that enables you to display shipping cost. On the other hand, the user is moving backward in a process, possibly seeing information (shipping cost) that wasn’t there on the last visit. The same goes for a user having an account where she has provided shipping details, which would enable you to show the information on the first page. However, you don’t know for sure in the check-out process that this information won’t be changed. A registered user could change the shipping address on this particular delivery because it’s a gift to an aunt or a shipment to another office. You don’t know.

So my recommendation would be to stick to a forward phasing process, only displaying shipping cost when you actually know where to ship. You keep the process clean, predictable and don’t confuse user with additional information based on the following screen. Making user confused in a check-out process is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely should show shipping cost in shopping cart if it's possible. 
I would even include shipping calculator in shopping cart at the very beginning. The thing is that customers want to know what they going to pay as soon as possible. So why should they go to checkout to see the totals if they can do it earlier in shopping cart?